# How to redirect external IP requests to localhost

Tags: centos, iptables

I am on Centos 6, I have iptables
I have a service running on localhost:5000
I need to open this service to the internet

I have tried 
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d [myip] -j DNAT --to-destination [localhost]`
but the system outputs an error saying that PREROUTING is a bad option/flag

I want to be able to go to `myip:5000` in the browser and the request to come into `localhost:5000`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is your under a NAT, or do you have a public IP?

Comment: ofcourse, Public IP

Comment: Did you open your port through the centos firewall?